# How to show the quotient of dual space and the annihilator of its subspace is equal to dual of the subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, duality-theorems, random-matrices

Let $W$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$ over a field $F$. Let $i : W \to V $ denote the inclusion map.

Show that $ \pi: V^*\to W^*$given by $\pi(f) = f\circ i$ is a surjective linear map, with kernel equal to $W^0$. Hence show that $W^* = V^*/W^o$.

Comment: Yup @Amitai Yuval

Comment: Related:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741056/the-dual-of-subspace-of-a-normed-space-is-a-quotient-of-dual-x-u-perp-con

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spelled out differently, all you need to observe is that every linear functional on $W$ can be linearly extended to $V$. The statement then follows from the definition.